# Get value/id of activated input in an ASP MVC Ajax.BeginForm OnBegin method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My ASP MVC cshtml code

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("action", "controller", new {para=123},  
       new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    OnBegin = "DoOnBegin",
                }))
            {
                <input type="submit" value="foo" id="fooSubmit" />
                <input type="submit" value="bar" id="barSubmit" />
            }
```

and the javascript

```
function DoOnBegin() {
  if(value of activated input element == "foo"){
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get the value of the input element that was clicked and if it is, how? The $(this) element contains only the form but it seems like I can't get the selected input.

Either a pure javascript or a jquery solution would be fine

Comment: I'd suggest jQuery only instead of Ajax helpers.

Comment: Why do you want to get the input element?  Are you looking to do something to it on the server-side?  On the client side?

Comment: I want to change a value in a table cell to a different value based on which input is selected.

Comment: so give your input buttons id first. And is there any condition for which one of them will remain disabled

Comment: Neither of the input buttons is disabled, I'll add the IDs